# I don't know how to add a .php file to the permalink structure of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I wasn't sure how to word this question, so i'll just explain.

I want my form at www.blog.com/got-a-question/ to be sent to a verify.php however when I do it sends it to a non-existent www.blog.com/got-a-question/verify.php

Where and how exactly do I direct to the verify page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't about the permalink structure of WordPress; all you need to do is add a slash to the action attribute in the form

so instead of

`<form action="verify.php" method="post">`

do

`<form action="/verify.php" method="post">`

Note the slash before verify.php; that signals to the browser to post it at the root directory (blog.com/verify.php) instead of on top of the last directory.

(The permalink structure is only relevant to the extent that the lack of a file suffix confuses the browser into thinking got-a-question is a folder rather than a file, so it tries to stack on top of it.)

Comment: the verify.php lies in the same theme folder as the gotaquestion.php file in the theme folder

Comment: i'll just add the whole path wp-content/themes/showtimev1.5_thisone/verify.php ... I just though there would be a more elegant way of doing this without showing the whole path.

Comment: Ah, you can use a WordPress function for the theme directory: `get_bloginfo( 'template_directory')`. But, yes, this is an annoying facet of the nature of WordPress's file structure.

Comment: @Adam didn't see your first comment. /wp-content/themes/showtimev1.5_thisone/gotaquestion.php and /got-a-question aren't related to eachother as far as the browser can tell, even if the latter is just an include of the former.